# PHP $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT'] is empty

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ssl, ssl-certificate

What I'm trying to do is pass a client certificate to my PHP page. For testing, I'm using `curl` on a Linux terminal:

```
curl --cert cert.pem 'https://example.com/test.php'
```

On *test.php*, I have it set to print the `$_SERVER` superglobal:

```
<?php
    print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

In Apache, I have the following options:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ...
    SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
    SSLVerifyDepth  1
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
    ...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Upon executing my `curl` command, I am seeing that the `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']` variable is empty:

```
Array
(
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SSL_TLS_SNI] => example.com
    [SSL_SERVER_CERT] => -- REDACTED --

    [SSL_CLIENT_CERT] =>
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
    [HTTP_HOST] => example.com
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443</address>

    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
    [SERVER_NAME] => example.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.1.26.199
    [SERVER_PORT] => 443
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 10.1.26.241
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /vol1/sites
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => [no address given]
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /vol1/sites/test.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 33400
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] =>
    [REQUEST_URI] => /test.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /test.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /test.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1487370411
)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the Apache log files?

Comment: @HBruijn Negative. Only that I requested the file in the _access.log_.

Comment: do you have another virtualhost definition that is catching this request? did you try doing a wireshark to ensure curl is sending the cert?

Comment: @gbolo There is only one virtualhost setup for SSL connections. And no I haven't tried capturing curl's packets, but I have no reason to believe that it wouldn't be sending them.

Comment: @RyanSteffer check the cert format, from the doc -- `The certificate must be in PKCS#12 format if using Secure Transport, or PEM format if  using any other engine.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel foolish! But here is what fixed it for me:

Instead of defining the Virtual Host as `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`, it should be defined with an asterisk: `<VirtualHost *:443>`.

The default Apache installation has the `_default_` line, which is easy enough to overlook until you need to change it!